# Woocommerce product page custom layout

Tags: wordpress, layout, woocommerce

I'm trying to create custom layout, for woocommerce singke product page, using content-single-product.php. I know I need to create different div but really don't know how to do that properly...

[What I 'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fltli.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do template-override on woocommerce-templates.

create the folder "woocommerce" inside your theme-folder and then copy the original template into your woocommerce-folder including subfolders.

then you can just change the html as you needed.